# Linq Projection Count By Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to Linq Projection. I just want to know how to count by Id. I need to count orders for every customer and average order price.

```
public IQueryable<TemporaryCustomerModel> GetCustomersWithOrdersCountAndAveragePrice()
    {
        var result = dataContext.Customers
        .Include(u => u.Order)
        .Select(r => new TemporaryCustomerModel()
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            FullName = r.Name + ' ' + r.Surname,
            Email = r.Email,
            Birthdate = r.Birthdate,
            Gender = r.Gender.GetName(),
            Orders = ???, //Count orders for every customer
            AvgPrice = ??? //Average order price
        });

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposes that your `Customer` class contains `List<Order> Orders` and the `Order` class contains field `Price`

```
...
Orders = r.Orders.Count(),
AvgPrice = r.Orders.Average(o => o.Price)
...
```

Comment: Count is working now, but Price I have in table Product (in table Order i have Quantity).

Comment: so, continue Include and get the price. like r.Orders.Select(o=> o.Product.Price).Average()

Comment: Oh, now i got it, both are working, thanks! And one more question, Average price has more than 2 digits after comma, i need only 2, how to do it?

Comment: see Math.Round https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2